# Understanding the Generic Foreign Key in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to understand the Generic Foreign Key in Django. I just ran an input script that worked, but I still have questions:

All the inserted rows refer to the same content_type, so it makes sense that they all have the same content_type_id, in this case, 35. But where did the number 35 come from? Do I have 34 other content_types somewhere else, like in the default use Django has for content_type? (No, I checked that). How is the use of this number different from a PK or an FK?

The object_id is, like my primary keys, a uuid. These all seem to be different per row. But what is the object being identified by this number? Since Generic Foreign Key takes GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id') as args, maybe this is the ‘generic’ foreign key of that row’s relationship to my content_type? Or is it the generic foreign key to any and all future content_types this row might be connected to by me later? Since in this case they are all pointing to the same content object, why didn’t they all get the same object_id, just as they all got the same content_type_id?

Answer (score 1):

You're over complicating things.

The content type id is the id of the target model in the ContentType table. So yes there are - or have been at some point - at least 34 other content types in your database.

And the object id is the id - ie the primary key - of the target object. Of course they're all different; if they were all the same they would all refer to the same object.